# how to repair master database in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

For some unknown reasons, all of a sudden my sql servers master database has been corrupted and sql service won't run. I have spent hours and tried various things like trying to run the service under different accounts, also checked that no compression is set in the data folder etc but nothing seems to work. I copied master database from another instance and the service would start and I can connect to the database instance via management studio but I won't see my databases. I have backup of the corrupted master database (mdf and log file) but just wondering how can we fix this database to see all my databases? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restore from the backup (good to have one!), it's the recommended way:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2011/02/01/the-easiest-way-to-rebuild-the-sql-server-master-database.aspx

In case you don't have a good backup, you will have to rebuild master database:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Copying over from another existing instance is not recommended.

Comment: Does sql server 2005 automatically create backup of master database? If so where would it create it?

Comment: No, it doesn't -- but you said that you have backup, didn't you?

Comment: Sorry I just meant that I have copy of mdf and log file of the corrupted database

Comment: I have run this command start /wait <CD or DVD Drive>\setup.exe /qn INSTANCENAME=<InstanceName> REINSTALL=SQL_Engine REBUILDDATABASE=1 SAPWD=<NewStrongPassword> and I can see new master database has been created but I still dont see my databases in the management studio. Do I need to manually attach all the databases and create users again

Comment: Yes, what you have now is a blank master database; attach other databases and recreate logins.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to attach all databases at once or it has to be done one by one

Comment: No, you have to attach databases one by one.